# Lombok builder, build half of the object, then finish building the other half

Tags: java, lombok

I have a class:

```
@Builder
public class Foo {
   private String id;
   private String a;
   private String b;
}
```

I want to build an object with some restrictions. I want all the objects built to have a value `a`, but I want to make a check, and only if the object's `id` is in a `List`, I want to build it's 'b' value.

```
...

for(Foo foo: foos) {
   Foo.FooBuilder builder = Foo.builder();
   builder.a("bar1");

   if(listOfIds.contains(foo.getId)) {
      builder.b("bar2");
   }
   foo = builder.build();
}
...
```

That is an example of my code. So, I'm asking if this is the correct way to do it with the builder, or is there a better way to do this using builder.

Comment: You above code does nothing as the newly built `Foo` does never get used. This makes your question rather invalid.

Comment: My question was how to use builder to partially build Foo object, and later update it using builder, if it is needed. So, Tran Ho gave me an acceptable answer. I don't understand you comment.

Comment: Now, it's better... the assignment in your last line wouldn't do anything useful, but it indicates clearly what you wanted. Concerning the answer: Consider moving the whole code into the conditional (as otherwise, your builder don't get used anyway). Consider using `@Builder(toBuilder=true)` for copying all properties to the builder or using [`@With`](https://projectlombok.org/features/With) for creating a modified copy of `foo`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATED

In case you want to modify every element in the list. You can try this code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < foos.size();i++) {
  Foo.FooBuilder builder = Foo.builder();
  builder.a("bar1");

  if(listOfIds.contains(foo.getId())) {
  builder.b("bar2");
  //TODO: copy other values from `foos.get(i)` to builder. It's your turn
  //update modified to the list at i
  foos.set(i, builder.build());   
}
```

}

=========================

Assume that `foo` is a `Foo` object. Then your code will not be compiled. You just need to set property `a` of the builder like my code. After setting all the properties in the `Foo` builder, run `builder.build()` to get your `foo`.

```
Foo.FooBuilder builder = Foo.builder();

for(Foo foo: foos) {
  builder.a("bar1");

  if(listOfIds.contains(foo.getId())) {
    builder.b("bar2");
  }

  foo = builder.build();

}
```

Comment: So, I edited the question. Can you look at it now, and give me an answer ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do but if you want to modify the element in `foos`, then it's a worng implementation, honestly. Builder will return a completely new `Foo`. At this time, the object `foo` will point to the address of the new object that the builder created.

Comment: Yes, I want to modify the element in foos. So my question is how do I do that ?